# Ratios in C# (in Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics, angle

I am attempting to apply ratios to move an object in a physics library.

I have programmed a swipe sort of functionality by taking the measuring the speed of the mouse swipe, along with the positions when you first click and when you let go.

I would like to apply force in a 2d space according to the angle that you swiped. I have tried using Mathf.Atan2 as well as the Vector2.angle method to find the angle that you swiped but to no avail.

I was thinking perhaps I could look at the x and y movement and then apply the appropriate force distribution along x and y axis from there?

For instance: You moved half as much x as y. So we will split the speed variable 1/3 moving in the x direction, and 2/3 force going in the y direction.

Is there an easier way to apply this sort of "swipe" style input into motion?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MouseInteraction : MonoBehaviour {
    public int SpeedMultiplier = 2;
    public Vector2 startPos;
    public Vector2 endPos;
    public float startTime;
    public float endTime;
    public float mouseDistance;
    public float mouseTime;
    public float mouseSpeed;
    public float mouseAngle;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) 
                {
                        Vector2 startPos = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint (Input.mousePosition);
                        float startTime = Time.time;
                        Debug.Log ("The start position is " + startPos);
                        Debug.Log ("The start time is " + startTime);
                }
        else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp (0)) 
                {
                    Vector2 endPos = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint (Input.mousePosition);
                    float endTime = Time.time;
                    Debug.Log ("The end position is " + endPos);
                    Debug.Log ("The end time is " + endTime);
                    float mouseDistance = Vector2.Distance(startPos, endPos);
                    Debug.Log ("The mouse distance is " + mouseDistance);
                    float mouseTime = endTime - startTime;
                    Debug.Log ("The mouse time is " + mouseTime);
                    float mouseSpeed = mouseDistance/ mouseTime;
                    Debug.Log ("The mouse SPEED is " + mouseSpeed);
                    float mouseAngleX = endPos.x - startPos.x;
                    float mouseAngleY = endPos.y - startPos.y;
                    Debug.Log ("The mouseX number is " +mouseAngleX);
                    Debug.Log ("The mouseY number is " +mouseAngleY);

                    }
    }
}
```

Specifically, I should add that the only thing I'm stuck on now is applying the correct amount of horizontal and verticle momentum. I could just multiply each mouseAngleX and mouseAngleY (the difference between the starting and ending position) to the Speed but then longer swipes would give much more force. A short and fast swipe should be just as good as a long one. Perhaps I can multiply/round to find some sort of solution where small and large swipes both will give the correct force?

Comment: So to clarify, it doesn't matter how fast or long the swipe is, all you need is the angle? So if someone had a long fast swipe in a certain direction, the same force will apply to it if they had a short, slow swipe in the same direction?

Answer (score 0):

You can just take the mouse swipe and normalize it. Then you can multiply it by a constant speed of your choosing.